# Python barbs wrong direction

Tags: python

There is probably a really simple answer to this and I'm only asking as a last resort as I usually get my answers by searching but I can't figure this out or find an answer. Basically I'm plotting some wind barbs in Python but they are pointing in the wrong direction and I don't know why.

Data is imported from a file and put into lists, I found on another stackoverflow post how to set the U, V for barbs using np.sin and np.cos, which results in the correct wind speed but the direction is wrong. I'm basically plotting a very simple tephigram or Skew-T.

```
# Program to read in radiosonde data from a file named "raob.dat"

# Import numpy since we are going to use numpy arrays and the loadtxt
# function.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Open the file for reading and store the file handle as "f"
# The filename is 'raob.dat'

f=open('data.dat')
# Read the data from the file handle f.  np.loadtxt() is useful for reading
# simply-formatted text files.
datain=np.loadtxt(f)
# Close the file.
f.close();

# We can copy the different columns into
# pressure, temperature and dewpoint temperature

# Note that the colon means consider all elements in that dimension.
# and remember indices start from zero
p=datain[:,0]
temp=datain[:,1]
temp_dew=datain[:,2]
wind_dir=datain[:,3]
wind_spd=datain[:,4]

print 'Pressure/hPa: ', p
print 'Temperature/C: ', temp
print 'Dewpoint temperature: ', temp_dew
print 'Wind Direction/Deg: ', wind_dir
print 'Wind Speed/kts: ', wind_spd

# for the barb vectors. This is the bit I think it causing the problem
u=wind_spd*np.sin(wind_dir)
v=wind_spd*np.cos(wind_dir)

#change units
#p=p/10
#temp=temp/10
#temp_dew=temp_dew/10

#plot graphs
fig1=plt.figure()
x1=temp
x2=temp_dew
y1=p
y2=p
x=np.linspace(50,50,len(y1))
#print x
plt.plot(x1,y1,'r',label='Temp')
plt.plot(x2,y2,'g',label='Dew Point Temp')
plt.legend(loc=3,fontsize='x-small')
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
#fig2=plt.figure()
plt.barbs(x,y1,u,v)
plt.yticks(y1)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

The barbs should all mostly be in the same direction as you can see in the direction in degrees from the data.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the data that is used:

```
996 25.2    24.9    290 12
963.2   24.5    22.6    315 42
930.4   23.8    20.1    325 43
929 23.8    20  325 43
925 23.4    19.6    325 43
900 22  17  325 43
898.6   21.9    17  325 43
867.6   20.1    16.5    320 41
850 19  16.2    320 44
807.9   16.8    14  320 43
779.4   15.2    12.4    320 44
752 13.7    10.9    325 43
725.5   12.2    9.3 320 44
700 10.6    7.8 325 45
649.7   7   4.9 315 44
603.2   3.4 1.9 325 49
563 0   -0.8    325 50
559.6   -0.2    -1  325 50
500 -3.5    -4.9    335 52
499.3   -3.5    -5  330 54
491 -4.1    -5.5    332 52
480.3   -5  -6.4    335 50
427.2   -9.7    -11 330 45
413 -11.1   -12.3   335 43
400 -12.7   -14.4   340 42
363.9   -16.9   -19.2   350 37
300 -26.3   -30.2   325 40
250 -36.7   -41.2   330 35
200 -49.9   0   335 0
150 -66.6   0   0   10
100 -83.5   0   0   30
```

Liam

Answer (score 3):

```
# for the barb vectors. This is the bit I think it causing the problem
u=wind_spd*np.sin(wind_dir)
v=wind_spd*np.cos(wind_dir)
```

Instead try:

```
u=wind_spd*np.sin((np.pi/180)*wind_dir)
v=wind_spd*np.cos((np.pi/180)*wind_dir)
```

(http://tornado.sfsu.edu/geosciences/classes/m430/Wind/WindDirection.html)

Comment: "`np.sin` and `np.cos` takes the input as radians" is the sentence you are missing in your answer, otherwise you got it spot on.